# Error fetching YouTube thumbnails from img.youtube.com - HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found Error

Tags: php, youtube, http-status-code-404, thumbnails

I'm building a site on which users can share YouTube videos. Therefore I need to fetch a thumbnail from the youtube servers by using the `imagecreatefromjpeg` function of php. Unfortunately, this does not work with every video. Some videos only result in this error message:

> Warning:
>   imagecreatefromjpeg(http://img.youtube.com/vi/GY0wbp38REk/0.jpg)
>   [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in ....

My script checks from 0.jpg up to 4.jpg whether a thumbnail is available, but there seems to be no thumbnail for certain videos.

How can I get the thumbnail of these videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of guessing the address to the video, you have to use the [oEmbed data they provide](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html). Query `http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=` with the path to the url (`watch?v=...`) and parse the response, they provide thumbnail_url